# Выборка из базы по значению

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. В базе данных MySQL есть таблица **producers** , в которой содержаться записи, вида:

```
name: Дерево       |     id_sp: 10,22,39,55
name: Автомобиль   |     id_sp: 77,122,11,39
name: Фрукты       |     id_sp: 45,22,39,98
```

**id_sp** - VARCHAR

Каким образом выбрать из таблицы **producers** только те записи, в которых в столбце **id_sp** есть значения **22** и **39** (на пример). ?

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: вам следует задуматься о корректности вашей схемы данных. Связи многие-ко-многим реализуются через внешнюю таблицу. зы: `like` вам в помощь в данном случае

Comment: обратите внимание на [сей топик](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17308669/1216425)

Answer (score 2):

Тут вопрос к оператору сравнения строк: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/String_comparison_functions.html

Используя LIKE это можно провернуть.

Comment: в том то и дело что нельзя. не работает. точнее не выбирает все что должно.

Comment: Пример, пожалуйста.

Comment: > WHERE `id_sp` like '$option[id]'

Comment: в смысле? `select * from producers where id_sp like '%22%' and id_sp like %39%` не дает что надо?

Comment: Вот teran все правильно написал, вы % добавте

Comment: точно. спасибо огромное за помощь.

Comment: @Oma на самом деле, туда подойдут 222 и 390 :)

Comment: Пожалуйста, обращайтесь =)

Comment: @teran я думаю ему нужна сама суть проблемы, что тут подойдут и 1223 и 55522685 это понятно, пусть дорабатывает =)

Comment: @teran да, пошло все что не нужно и не нужно...

Comment: каким образом можно сделать вывод только нужных значений?

Comment: Лучше следовать стандарту и вообще такое не делать, а использовать либо отдельную таблицу, либо массив []varchar, так как любое сравнение строк в принципе, очень ресурсоемкий процесс

Comment: да, лучше. но уже сделано как сделано, проект старенький...